# Which Fedora should I use on VirtualBox?

Tags: fedora, virtualbox

The standard Fedora 36 release directory has the following options:

```
Cloud/
Container/
Everything/   
Kinoite/
Modular/
Server/ 
Silverblue/
Spins/     
Workstation/
```

My goal is to run a Node JS compiler for student's assignments on a VirtualBox environment. I need a minimal version that supports this.

Which one should I choose? Is the Cloud version applicable for this?

UPDATE

To be more clear: the task is to use Node JS through a terminal window, so no GUI is needed

Answer (score 0):

There are no* different Fedora versions, they are different sets of packages installed by default. You can use any.

* The only radically different version is Fedora Silverblue which is: *"However, unlike other operating systems, Silverblue is immutable. This means that every installation is identical to every other installation of the same version. The operating system that is on disk is exactly the same from one machine to the next, and it never changes as it is used"*.

> My goal is to run a Node JS compiler for student's assignments on a VirtualBox environment. I need a minimal version that supports this.

If you need UI, I'd highly recommend the XFCE spin which is the lightest and fastest in terms of CPU/RAM use: https://spins.fedoraproject.org/xfce/download